# Custom Peer to Peer Communication in Android using FCM

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, p2p

Earlier I used FCM Firbase for Push Notifications, Now I have a requirement in my App there are 2 groups of users 1) publishers & 2) subscribers whenever publisher changes their status should be known to subscribers, for this requirement can I use the FCM Firebase which should send status available message to all Subscribers.

All I knows is from the App server, FCM Push Notifications can be sent that are notified to users in Notification Status bar. Is it possible for the App to send status to FCM Firebase server which in-turn can broadcast the status to other peers in the network.

**UPDATE**

I can opt Data message feature in FCM, my only doubt is can FCM able to push the data event through peer-to-peer communication, earlier I had to trigger Push Notifications from App server,  just want to know if FCM can handle this directly

Answer (score 0):

This is not safe. You have to put the fcm authenticate json file at a client application -- it can be abused.